# What are the moral and ethical arguments surrounding the proposed legalization of the Ouroboros Steak?

Tags: ethics, legal, moral-dilemma

Apparently the future is lab-grown meat which will see the end of slaughtering animals. However buisness tycoons are apparently not stopping at animal meat, and are proposing to grow human meat. One dish made of human meat is called an Ouroboros Steak, which could literally be made at home using ones own cells.

[Dezeen](https://www.dezeen.com/2020/11/13/ouroboros-steak-meal-kit-andrew-pelling-grace-knight-orkan-telhan/)

> Ouroboros Steak could be grown by the diner at home using their own cells, which are harvested from the inside of their cheek and fed serum derived from expired, donated blood.

**Ouroboros Steak**

Apparently the Ouroboros Steak has sparked both interest and outrage.

[The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/07/arts/design/Ouroboros-Steak-design-museum.html)

> Steaks Grown From Human Cells Spark Interest and Outrage

**Financial industry**

According to The Scotsman lab-grown meat is already a multi-million pound industry, before it has even became legalized.

[The Scotsman](https://www.scotsman.com/read-this/scientists-have-created-an-edible-steak-made-from-human-cells-heres-why-3041565)

> Although no lab-grown meats are currently approved for sale anywhere in the world, the market is estimated to be worth $206 million, and expected to grow to $572 million by 2025.

**Cannibalism**

Conspiracy theorist David Icke is already twisting the words of mainstream newspapers and claiming that this is the beginning of legalizing cannibalism.

[David Icke](https://davidicke.com/2022/09/15/the-beginning-of-cannibalism-lab-grown-human-meat-is-now-being-proposed/)

> The Beginning of Cannibalism? Lab-Grown Human Meat Is Now Being Proposed

**Question**

What are the moral and ethical arguments surrounding the proposed legalization of the Ouroboros Steak?

Comment: The first issue is: if we agree that "lab-grown meat" is ok in order to feed humans avoiding cruelty toward animals (but the secondary issue will be: if we do not eat cow's meat, why grown cows at all?) etc, what is the benefit of producing also lab-grown human meat?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Pretty grim question "What's the purpose of letting another being live if it can't be exploited".

Comment: These articles describe an art project, in which the artists imagine eating meat grown from cells swabbed from your own cheek. The artists suggest that in the future, poor people who can't afford real meat might be forced to eat themselves, which makes no sense whatsoever. The passive voice in the Scotsman article leaves out who is making the economic predictions, but I bet it's also the artists. Maybe there's a legitimate question here, but I see no evidence that anything of this sort will ever actually happen, just a typical media cycle.